# Why can't I access my application delegate from a ViewController?

Tags: swift, cocoa

In my app, I would like to access delegate methods from a View Controller, but when I try to access it this way :

```
let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
```

I am getting `nil`, what could cause this ?

**EDIT WITH ADDITIONAL INFO :**
When I created the app, I did an error as I didn't choose to use storyboards, but when I needed them, I just added a storyboard file and defined it as the main interface, like this :
[image]

I believe my issue could come from here, **could it be possible for the interface to be shown but not linked properly to the NSApplication (and so to the delegate) ?

If yes, how could I solve it ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your storyboard, make sure that `App Delegate`'s custom class (in the **Identity Inspector**) is set to your delegate class.

[image]
[image]

**Update**

If you have just created a new `storyboard`, it will be empty. AFAIK there are no "standard" ways of creating the application scene. You have to *copy* it from another storyboard (they are just XMLs after all).

The simplest way would be creating a new project with `Use Storyboard` enabled, then right-click on your auto generated `Main.storyboard`, choose **Open As** ➔ **Source Code**. After that, copy the `<!--Application-->` part to your empty `Storyboard.storyboard`. Don't for get to grab the header and footer part of it, too. Below is just an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="7706" systemVersion="14D136" targetRuntime="MacOSX.Cocoa" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="B8D-0N-5wS">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaPlugin" version="7706"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
    <!--Application-->

    <!-- your copied content -->

    </scenes>
</document>
```

Finally, right-click on your `Storyboard.storyboard` and choose **Open As** ➔ **Interface Builder - Storyboard** to resume the normal design view.

Comment: I can't find App Delegate in the list  (nor application)

Comment: Nice! That's hardcore surgery but something I've done previously... fixed the issue for me after some tweaks